# Retain MM/dd/yyyy format when converting string value to DateTime

Tags: c#

I have a string containing value in the format of 11/22/2019 00:00:00

I want to store this in a DateTime column.

I have tried this:

```
DateTime date ;
DateTime dtVal;
// string abcd contains 11/22/2019 00:00:00
  abcd = date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(abcd, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out converteddate))
 {
 dtVal = converteddate;   // I am getting 22/11/2019 12:00:00
 }
```

I want the dtval value to hold the datetime value as  - 11/22/2019 00:00:00

How to achieve this ?
Thanks

Comment: `DateTime` stores the parsed value as a `long` and as such has no format, so this isn't possible. The only time you see a formatted value is after converting to a `string` (either automatically via the debugger, or through your own code to do so).

Comment: `// I am getting 22/11/2019 12:00:00` - how do you determine this?

Comment: You can't control the default string representation of a `DateTime` (for example in the debugger), nor should it matter. If you want your string to be portable, store it as one (after using the `ToString` with the appropriate format).

Comment: Since you are not using `am/pm` in your time. I suggest using `HH` instead of `hh` so it properly works with the 24-hour format.

Comment: hi. how to retain the string to be casted as datetime

Comment: @500-InternalServerError -  when i am debugging , i can see the value as 22/11/2019 12:00:00

Comment: @Venkat When you are debugging, the debugger will call `converteddate.ToString();` to show you the value.

Comment: @John -  does this mean dtVal actually stores in MM/dd/yyyy format and only during debugging it is showing value as dd/MM/yyyy format ?

Comment: No, if you refer to my first comment, `DateTime` stores the datetime as a `long` value: `.Ticks`. It has no concept of format whatsoever. It means that this number is taken, and formatted according to the thread culture when you call `.ToString()`.

Comment: [Examples](https://rextester.com/AUS74355)

Answer (score 3):

DateTime itself does not have its "natural" format, as John commented - it is internally "just a number" ;-) . The `ToString()` method depends on `Culture` you set.